# A simple voting mechanism in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet which has three columns. These three columns can have some value or be blank. I have to update a fourth column based on the entries in these three columns. The criteria for updating the fourth column is as follows:

1. **If two or more columns have same value then fourth column will have
   this same value.**
2. **If all three values are different then fourth column will have first
   non blank value.**
3. **If there is only one non blank value then fourth column will have
   that non blank value.**

I'm unable to figure out what should be the formula in fourth column for this criteria.

Here is an example
[image]

Comment: By the rule All three different so pick first non blank shouldn't row 8 be "a"?

Comment: Yes you are right, My bad. Will update this. Thank you

Comment: Also, are the only things entered going to be single characters? Or are longer strings going to be used? Also will you need to use a greater number of columns than just 3?

Comment: Yes. Could be string of any length (with no spaces). I just used single characters for example. And just three columns always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:C2,,MODE(MATCH(A2:C2,A2:C2, 0))), IF(A2="", IF(B2="", C2, B2), A2))
```

Just paste it to D2 and drag down.

To explain it, it looks for the `MODE` (Most common value) of everything in the range `A2:C2`.

```
MODE(MATCH(A2:C2, A2:C2, 0))
```

This would return the first position in which the most common value returns, in this case we use the `INDEX` function and get the value at the given index, in the range `A2:C2`.

```
INDEX(A2:C2,,MODE(MATCH(A2:C2,A2:C2, 0)))
```

This part so far is slightly based on code from [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/most-frequently-occurring-word.html)

Now this will give us the letter, but only if one letter is more common than the others, if they all have different values, then it'll return an error. In this case, we use the `IFERROR` function which, if there is an error in it's first argument, will instead calculate the second argument. So if there isn't a match, then we want to just get the first non blank cell.

So check if `A2` is blank, if it is check if `B2` is blank, if it is, use the cell value in `C2`, otherwise use the cell value in `B2`, but if `A2` is not blank, use the value in `A2`.

```
IF(A2="", IF(B2="", C2, B2), A2))
```

With a little bit of working around, you could probably turn the above statement into something that's a little more expandable (google first non-blank value in row or something like that).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works fine and is simpler. Though I get a 0 in place of blank in row 5

Comment: Select the Votes column. 
Go To Format>Cells>Number. 
Choose custom from the category list. 
In the Type box, paste `0;-0;;@` - From [Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/display-or-hide-zero-values-HP005199879.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Using your example, in cell D2 and copied down:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A2:C2)=0,"",IF(MAX(INDEX(COUNTIF(A2:C2,A2:C2),))>1,INDEX(A2:C2,MATCH(MAX(INDEX(COUNTIF(A2:C2,A2:C2),)),INDEX(COUNTIF(A2:C2,A2:C2),),0)),INDEX(A2:C2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:C2<>"",),0))))
```